# text not staying in same postion

Tags: html, css

Hey guys just got some text and i was wondering why in some resolutions when i zoom out and zoom in in the browser not stay in the same place. Its mainly happening in Firefox.

```
        <div class = "hello">
            <p>Hello This is just an example of what should go in here. When   youi move down to the bottom you will see what you need 2 enter. .</p>
        </div>
```

Below is my css which i have used to control it.

```
.hello
{
position:absolute;
top: 210px;
width:37em;
text-wrap:none;
text-align: left;
font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: A screenshot or a demo would be helpful.

Comment: I'm having the same issue - I have everything set in pixels, absolutely positioned and when I zoom in, the text changes a little so where the wrapping ended, it doesn't end in the same place anymore. The text jumps around as you zoom. This is VERY annoying and I can't figure out why it's happening.

Answer (score 0):

When you zoom in or out (Ctrl + or Ctrl -) everything on the page change his size. So, not only the `font-size` becomes bigger, also the `top` distance.

The behaviour you want can be achieved when the user changes the default font size in his browser preferences.

The only way to get this behaviour with Ctrl + and Ctrl - is doing some trick with JavaScript catching browser's zoom and modifying the `top` distance properly. However, I think this is not a good idea because Ctrl + and Ctrl - are specially useful for people with some visual problems and they are a standard behaviour in all browsers.

Comment: Yes i know this however when you zoom out on a specif time the text will overlap each other if you get what i mean

Comment: I can't reproduce what you are describing. Can you post some screenshot or demo?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with your absolute top positioning.  If you use this CSS:

```
    <style>
        .hello {position: absolute; width: auto;}
        .hello p {word-wrap:none; font-size:16px;}
    </style>
```

You'll notice the DIV remains in the same place just the line spacing and font-size increases.  If you want your DIV to remain in the exact same position you will need to use `position: fixed;`

Also `text-wrap:none;` is not a valid CSS parameter you should use `word-wrap:none;`.